# Data management with several variables

Tags: algorithm, stata

Currently I am facing the following problem, which I'm working in Stata to solve. I have added the algorithm tag, because it's mainly the steps that I'm interested in rather than the Stata code.

I have some variables, say, var1 - var20 that can possibly contain a string. I am only interested in some of these strings, let us call them A,B,C,D,E,F, but other strings can occur also (all of these will be denoted X). Also I have a unique identifier ID. A part of the data could look like this:

```
ID  |  var1  |  var2  |  var3  |  ..  |  var20  
1   |   E    |        |        |      |    X
1   |        |   A    |        |      |    C
2   |   X    |   F    |   A    |      |   
8   |        |        |        |      |    E
```

Now I want to create an entry for every ID and for every occurrence of one of the strings A,B,C,E,D,F in any of the variables. The above data should look like this:

```
ID  |  var1  |  var2  |  var3  |  ..  |  var20
1   |    E   |        |        |  ..  |       
1   |        |    A   |        |      |       
1   |        |        |        |      |    C
2   |        |    F   |        |      |
2   |        |        |    A   |      |
8   |        |        |        |      |    E
```

Here we ignore every time there's a string X that is NOT A,B,C,D,E or F. My attempt so far was to create a variable that for each entry counts the number, N, of occurrences of A,B,C,D,E,F. In the original data above that variable would be N=1,2,2,1. Then for each entry I create N duplicates of this. This results in the data:

```
ID  |  var1  |  var2  |  var3  |  ..  |  var20  
1   |   E    |        |        |      |    X
1   |        |   A    |        |      |    C
1   |        |   A    |        |      |    C
2   |   X    |   F    |   A    |      |   
2   |   X    |   F    |   A    |      |   
8   |        |        |        |      |    E
```

My problem is how do I attack this problem from here? And sorry for the poor title, but I couldn't word it any more specific.

Comment: Now I see. I updated my answer. You can get your middle block with two calls to `reshape`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I thought the finally block was your desired output (now I understand that it's what you've accomplished so far). You can get the middle block with two calls to `reshape` (`long`, then `wide`).

First I'll generate data to match yours.

```
clear
set obs 4

* ids
generate n = _n
generate id = 1 in 1/2
replace id = 2 in 3
replace id = 8 in 4

* generate your variables
forvalues i = 1/20 {
    generate var`i' = ""
}
replace var1 = "E" in 1
replace var1 = "X" in 3
replace var2 = "A" in 2
replace var2 = "F" in 3
replace var3 = "A" in 3
replace var20 = "X" in 1
replace var20 = "C" in 2
replace var20 = "E" in 4
```

Now the two calls to `reshape`.

```
* reshape to long, keep only desired obs, then reshape to wide
reshape long var, i(n id) string   
keep if inlist(var, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
tempvar long_id
generate int `long_id' = _n
reshape wide var, i(`long_id') string
```

The first `reshape` converts your data from wide to long. The `var` specifies that the variables you want to reshape to long all start with `var`. The `i(n id)` specifies that each unique combination of `n` and `i` is a unique observation. The `reshape` call provides one observation for each `n`-`id` combination for each of your `var1` through `var20` variables. So now there are 4*20=80 observations. Then I keep only the strings that you'd like to keep with `inlist()`.

For the second `reshape` call `var` specifies that the values you're reshaping are in variable `var` and that you'll use this as the prefix. You wanted one row per remaining letter, so I made a new index (that has no real meaning in the end) that becomes the `i` index for the second `reshape` call (if I used `n`-`id` as the unique observation, then we'd end up back where we started, but with only the good strings). The `j` index remains from the first `reshape` call (variable `_j`) so the `reshape` already knows what suffix to give to each `var`.

These two `reshape` calls yield:

```
. list n id var1 var2 var3 var20

     +-------------------------------------+
     | n   id   var1   var2   var3   var20 |
     |-------------------------------------|
  1. | 1    1      E                       |
  2. | 2    1             A                |
  3. | 2    1                            C |
  4. | 3    2             F                |
  5. | 3    2                    A         |
     |-------------------------------------|
  6. | 4    8                            E |
     +-------------------------------------+
```

You can easily add back variables that don't survive the two `reshape`s.

```
* if you need to add back dropped variables
forvalues i =1/20 {
    capture confirm variable var`i'
    if _rc {
        generate var`i' = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! This was nicely done with rcount - i will certainly use it. But this was only "half" of the problem. What I would like now is to the data to appear as in the middle data in my queston. That is, every line must only contain ONE of the strings A,B,..,F. I hope you have an idea on how this may be solved :) thanks

Comment: Also a certain string can appear more than once for each entry, and this has to be treated in the same way as if they were different. Also  I think that "expand my_count if(my_count>=2)" can replace your loop :)

Comment: I managed to finish the second "half" myself. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Oh, and you're right that `expand` can take a "vector" argument (I didn't pick this up from the help file), but you don't need to qualify with `if(my_count >= 2)` because it takes 1 to be no expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Couldn't quite get the reshape to work. Not sure i follow the line "reshape long var, i(n id) string". What is var ?

Comment: OK, I think I explained `reshape` a little better. `var` is the "stub" of your 20 variable names, which is `var`, at least how you posed the question (to use `reshape` your variables should be named with a pattern). `reshape` is one of the trickiest, but most useful, command in most stats languages. It is probably best to look at the output after each line. HTH.

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly! I really appreciate your help, and that reshape command is definitely useful. One last question if you don't mind. Suppose my variables are not called var1-var20 but instead they all contain the string "test". Is it then possible to do something along the lines of "reshape long *test*, i(n id) string"? This doesn't work, but maybe there's a way around.

Comment: @StefanHansen If your variables are `test1`, `test2`, etc, then `reshape long test` should work. It is also possible to have `test1stuff`, `test2stuff`, etc, using the `@` symbol. It may be best to start a new question asking to do the `reshape`.

Comment: The problem is that my variables could be something like "somethingtest9", "sometingelsetest8", "testtest10" for example. I opened another question asking how to smartly rename these to var1-var20 for example. Thanks for this.

Comment: I see there's a question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191408/renaming-variables-that-contain-a-certain-string