# Renaming variables that contain a certain string

Tags: stata

I have a list of variables all containing the same string "test". How do I rename all of these variables to for example var1-var20, where 20 is the number of variables. The order is not important here. I tried installing the package "renvars", and did the following

```
renvars *test* \ var1-var20
```

but this does not work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error? It seems that this should work. Can you provide the variable names?

Comment: Can't recall all the variable names as i'm not sitting with the data in front of me. But they are along the lines of "hodiag_icd8", "akdiag_icd10". All have "icd" involved somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be any more help we'll need the error and how it fails. `*test*` *should* be a valid `varlist` and if there are the same numbers of variables in each varlist (left and right of `\`), the it *should* work.

The following works for me.

```
* generate some variables that fit the description
clear
local i = 0
foreach pre in ho ak {
    forvalues j = 1/10 {
        local ++i
        generate `pre'_icd`i' = ""
    }
}

* rename variables that match pattern
renvars *icd* \ var1-var20
```

Maybe more variables match `*icd*` than you expect?

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I'll have to check up on this on monday, when I have data before me again. I'll get back to you.

Comment: You were right. There were 19 and not 20 variables matching the *icd* tag. Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Stata 12, I think you should be able to just do:

```
rename (*test*) var#, addnumber
```

Check out this link (in particular Rule #18): http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?rename+group